# Using String as BST key value

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree which stores objects. For inserting objects to it I am using Int value as a key. I get that value by calling method form the object like this:

```
public class Tree
{
    // The root node of the tree which is null;
    private Node root;
    private double largest;

    private Node insert (Node tree, Element d)
    {
        if (tree == null)  return new Node(d);
        else if (d.getPlaceInTable() < tree.data.getPlaceInTable()) tree.left = insert (tree.left, d);
        else if (d.getPlaceInTable() > tree.data.getPlaceInTable()) tree.right = insert (tree.right, d);

    return tree;

    }

    public void insert (Element d)
    {
    root = insert (root, d);
    }
```

But what if I want to use Elements name as a key value which is string? How can I do it? Should I use compareTo() method? I know how to compare string1.compareTo(string2) but I really don' have any idea how I can use it in this case. If you have any suggestions, I really appreciate that.

Comment: yes, String implements Comparable, so you can do `d.getName().compareTo(tree.data.getName()) > 0`

Comment: thank you for your help, it worked just as I supposed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, String implements Comparable, so you can do

`d.getName().compareTo(tree.data.getName()) < 0` for the left node and
   `d.getName().compareTo(tree.data.getName()) >= 0` for the right node

Also note, that in your original code you do not insert anything in your tree when values are equal.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I am ignoring equal values, because I am storing elements from periodic table, which are not equal to each other.